# How can I know what engine is compatible with a 2001 Mazda 626

Tags: engine, mazda

I am selecting an engine to go into this vehicle and I want to know what my options are.  What I know is that the engine that was a 2.5L, The transmission is standard.  Wikipedia says the 2.5L engine in the 1998 series was a KL-G4.  In looking for a replacement Engine, I have found another k-series, namely a KL-ZE.  How can I know what I am getting into if I decide to buy a different model engine in the K-series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend putting in a different engine unless you want to deal with changing/splicing the wiring harness and installing a new computer. I would just stick with the same type of engine that came with the car.

Engine swaps in newer fuel injected vehicles is not what I would call "fun."